# Gateway Time-out:The gateway did not receive a timely response from the upstream server

Tags: php, apache, cloud, cloudflare

I am sending 300 newsletter at a time with a url, after 2 min it refresh itself again to send next 300 at so on.

But I am getting this error:

> Gateway Time-out
>
> The gateway did not receive a timely response from the upstream server
>   or application.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I have set max execution to 3600

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 3600);
```

But I am regularly getting same error. Please help me to find out the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem and I used `ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 6000);` to fix it.
http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.default-socket-timeout

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem. After i changed my php.ini file

1. default_socket_timeout = 240
2. max_execution_time = 240
   to fix it.

Comment: Is this an answer or another question?

Answer (score 0):

"Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

This would indicate something is not configured properly on the server.

Can't follow why you think this is a CloudFlare issue right now (from the tag). Are you getting a [CloudFlare error message](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/sections/200038216-CloudFlare-Error-Messages) at all?

Answer (score 0):

if the problem is coming from   sql sentence, is a server's processing the long query try to optimize the SQL Sentence

Answer (score 0):

I have 18,600,000 rows in my table. `TimeOut` error was over when I set the `TimeOut` to 6000 in `http.conf` after the `ServerRoot`.